# Linker error when I build using PODS - linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Tags: ios, objective-c, build, cocoapods

I have been battling with this for 2 days.  I converted from static Frameworks to PODS.  I had 2 google pods; pod 'GoogleMaps'
pod 'GooglePlaces'.

Very first build it worked fine.

I then added another pod and so ran 'pod update'.

Then when I tried to build it, failed.  I tried numerous things, read every post I could find, and finally I uninstalled pod completely, deleted it from the workspace etc. and started again.  Same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously running pod update was changing something.

After investigation the variable it was changing was :

**Build Active Architecture** in the POD Project File.

From my reading, For PODS to work, this variable has to be the same in :
- your project Project File
- your project Target file
- your POD Project File

I had all 3 set to NO.

But when I ran 'pod update' the value in POD Project file was changed.

So after running 'pod update' I changed the value in 'POD Project file' back to NO (for both debug and release), build again and VOILA it works.

What a nightmare that was.  Hope this helps someone else.